# Why Quartz Scheduler stops working on Heroku after x minutes?

Tags: java, heroku, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to create a similar application like the one mentioned here https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-java-quartz-rabbitmq suggested on Heroku by this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes-java-quartz-rabbitmq.
The only difference is that at the moment I have a `web` app doing nothing (`"Hello World"`) and a `scheduler` app printing the current time.
Unfortunately, after 30 min that I'm not using the application, both `web` and `scheduler` stop working:

```
2020-02-09T15:20:17.911457+00:00 app[scheduler.1]: 15:20:17.911 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-02-09T15:20:18.151399+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:20:18.151 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2020-02-09T15:20:18.151689+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:20:18.151 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2020-02-09T15:20:18.151775+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:20:18.151 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2020-02-09T15:20:18.151840+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:20:18.151 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2020-02-09T15:20:18.152244+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:20:18.152 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
2020-02-09T15:20:18.152871+00:00 app[web.1]: 15:20:18.152 [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-02-09T15:20:18.135436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-02-09T15:20:18.247822+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-02-09T15:20:18.123889+00:00 heroku[scheduler.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

The `Procfile` is pretty simple:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar
scheduler: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/*.jar -Dloader.main=algotrading.app.scheduler.SchedulerApp org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Is there something I am missing in the example?
Regards
  R

Comment: Have you read this? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping

Comment: Hi @codefinger, yes, but in my opinion the exceptions mentioned in that post about `worker` dynos should apply to `scheduler` dynos... otherwise it is a broken feature...


Edited after I see that you work for Heroku:
so just to recap, have I to purchase an Hobby dyno to have the scheduler dyno working as expected for the whole day?
Thanks

Comment: I tried configuring the `SchedulerApp` as `worker`, but it stops anyway... So I'm wondering if the following sentence is true: `Worker dynos do not sleep, because they do not respond to web requests. Be mindful of this as they may run 24/7 and consume from your pool of hours`

Comment: Do you see a SIGTERM for the worker/scheduler in the logs?

Comment: Hi @codefinger and thanks. Yes I can see: `Stopping all processes with SIGTERM` followed by `Process exited with status 143` for both dynos (`web` and `worker`)

Comment: Just to tell you @codefinger: I won't remain with a free dyno on this product... I need to create an algotrading software to do things I'm doing manually that are error prone and in sequence due to the fact that I'm alone. I'll purchase dynos and in the future a DB (probably postgresql), but at the moment I am in alpha stage and I want to be sure that Heroku fits with my requirements...

Comment: I think you'll need to open a support ticket at https://help.heroku.com

Answer (score 1):

I opened a ticket as suggested by @codefinger and I received immediate support. The answer to my question is that when you are using a `web` dyno with free dynos, when it becomes idle (due to dyno sleeping) all other dynos will become idle too.

This is the expected behaviour.
They will update the documentation as soos as they can.